# Create grid with instanced meshes in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a 10x10 grid of instanced cubes in three.js such that the meshes display as:

'[image: mesh grid]

but I can't seem to get my y axis position logic correct.

Here is my current code:

```
   
    const box_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
    const box_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        color: 0x0000ff,
    } ); 

    const box = new THREE.InstancedMesh(box_geometry, box_material, 100);
    scene.add(box);

    const dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        for(let j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            dummy.position.z = ((i * 21) - 95);
            dummy.position.y = (j * 2.5)
            // need y axis logic
        }
        console.log(dummy.position)
        dummy.updateMatrix();
        box.setMatrixAt(i, dummy.matrix);
    }
```

and here is the output:

[image: current box positioning]

I believe the loner box is the original `box` mesh, not a dummy. How can I fix my y-axis logic?